# Pass the child index to selector list dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to fetch the fields on the form for my automation. There are three fields on the form. And based on some particular value of first field, form adds the additional field after the first field on the same row.

Fields are divided into columns breakpoint on the row.
Thus how can I pass this column child index dynamically to helper method to fetch the fields.

Selectorlist looks like below:

```
selectorList: ".demo-row:nth-child(3) .demo-col-3:nth-child(1)"
```

I tried something like this which does not work:

```
field(index){
    selectorList: ".demo-row:nth-child(3) .demo-col-3:nth-child(${index})"
}
```

Throws error: invalid selector list.

Comment: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) use `\``, not double quotes.

Comment: Also the contents of the `field` method is invalid syntax.

Comment: Yeah, my bad.. I do not have `get` as prefix as getter does not accept params.

Comment: Using back-quote `\``, resolved the issue.